# How do I apply a flat texture to the side of an object?

Tags: texturing

Okay so imagine this, I take a plane with an image on it, and shoot pixels as lines perpendicular to the plane and they hit the object, coloring it. These lines do not pass through the object, they only color the first point they hit. That way, when viewed from the angle the object was painted from, the object shows the image nearly perfectly and the model looks convincingly painted, from all angles. Can I do this?

Comment: Hello. That looks promising, but a bit broad, could you add some pictures of what you want to do?

Comment: Try UV unwrapping your object using "project from view",  while at your preferred viewing angle, and see if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: "Decal" might be the term you're looking for, lots of good tutorials for that.